# Check if the Health apps are installed on user's device. (Swift)

Tags: swift, url-scheme

I've checked few questions on the internet and understood how to check other apps programatically. However, I'd like to check if some particular apps are installed on the user's device, take Google fit and FitBit for example. How would I check these apps on users device?
I'm not able to find any URLScheme for these apps.

Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't sound like a good plot.  Would you like somebody else's app to find out what types of apps are installed on your iPhone?

Comment: totally understandable, however, my motive is to show the user what are the apps that our app supports and then we can integrate to, to get the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your Info.plist

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fitbit</string>
    </array>
```

You can create common function to check availability of any scheme

```
func schemeAvailable(scheme: String) -> Bool {
        if let url = URL(string: scheme) {
            return UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url)
        }
        return false
}
```

Then, in code your can check to see if you can open FitBit

```
  self.schemeAvailable(scheme: "fitbit://")
```